# Installing Ghostscript on OpenWRT

Tags: ghostscript, openwrt, graphicsmagick

I am trying to annotate a text to an image with GraphicsMagick on an OpenWRT device.

It seems that "GhostScript" is missing, as it failes with:

```
    execvp failed, errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
    gm convert: "gs" "-q" "-dBATCH" "-dSAFER" "-dMaxBitmap=50000000" "-dNOPAUSE" "-sDEVICE=ppmraw"         "-dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4" "-r72x72" "-g84x24" "-sOutputFile=/tmp/gmjlUWKI" "--" "/tmp/gmEWyXw4" "-c" "quit".
```

The command "gs" can not be found.

So I would like to install GhostScript, but I can't find it as an opkg package.
Can someone tell me, how to install GhostScript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Clone the source from the Git repository, ./autogen.sh from the directory, execute make install from the directory.

There are more instructions in the [documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/Make.htm)